# PayPal hide order total

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal's REST API to implement paying via PayPal into my website.  When I send an approval request to PayPal it always shows the order total.  I really don't want to show this.  At the point in which we are asking for approval the user won't even know what their total order amount will be.  Is there anyway to hide the order total on the PayPal page?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending line items in your API request? For example:

```
  "item_list": {
    "items": [{
            "name": "Test",
            "sku": "18",
            "price": "7.47",
            "currency": "USD",
            "quantity": "1"
        }

    ]
  }
```

If you send the items array, the price will be displayed in PayPal's payment page.

However, you can just send a total amount, and it won't appear during buyer approval, for example:

```
{
"intent": "sale",
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://URL.com/restapi_test/_payments_execute-an-approved-paypal-payment.html",
    "cancel_url": "http://URL.com/restapi_test/_payments_create-a-payment-paypal.html"
},
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
},
"transactions": [{
    "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
}]
}
```

Comment: I am not sending a full item list.  I don't want those to show.  The order total does not show in their "classic" system however in their new system it does.

Comment: Hey Mike, I just tried again with the same API request as above, and the amount is not being displayed in the new layout (white/blue pattern).

Comment: I am pretty much doing what you are doing.  I only pass in an amount field and no line items.  Mine shows though :(.  I was hoping there was some custom styles I could add in my admin section

Comment: Do you have a debug Id for your initial API request? It should be returned in the "Paypal-Debug-Id" header.